# Как изменить фоновое видео на HTML-странице через определенное время?

Tags: javascript, html

Я бы хотел сделать 2 фоновое видео на страницу.  Первое видео фиксируется на указанный период времени, второе после предыдущего и является постоянным.

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так:

```js
$(".one").delay(2000).fadeOut(function() { //2000 это две секунды
  $(".two").fadeIn();
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">Первый</div>
<div class="two" style="display:none;">Второй</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Шахзод если подходит. примите в виде ответа.